# R - calculating the average value of a dataframe column from the top row to bottom row

Tags: r

The title may not be that clear, since it was difficult to summarize the problem in a few words, although I don't think the problem is that difficult to solve. To explain the problem, let me share a dataframe for reference:

```
head(df, n = 10)

     team     score 
1       A        10       
2       A         4        
3       A        10        
4       A        16        
5       A        20        
6       B         5
7       B        11         
8       B         8    
9       B        16         
10      B         5
```

I'd like to add a third column, that calculates the average score for each team, with the average score updating as I go down the rows for each team, and then resetting at a new team. For example, the output column I am hoping for would look like this:

```
head(df, n = 10)

     team     score   avg_score
1       A        10          10 
2       A         4           7
3       A        10           8
4       A        16          10
5       A        20          12
6       B         5           5
7       B        11           8 
8       B         8           8
9       B        16          10 
10      B         5           9


# row1: 10 = 10  
# row2: 7 = (10 + 4)/2  
# row3: 8 = (10 + 4 + 10)/3   
# ...
```

with the pattern following, and the calculation restarting for a new team.

Thanks,

Comment: Always nice to give reproducible data for such questions. Example `df <- data.frame(team = rep(c("A","B"), length.out = 10L, each = 5),
                 score = c(10, 4, 10, 16, 20, 5, 11, 8, 16, 5)) `

Comment: FYI dplyr has a `cummean` function for calculating the cumulative mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library("data.table")
setDT(df)[, `:=` (avg_score = cumsum(score)/1:.N), by = team]
```

or more readable as per the comment by @snoram

```
setDT(dt)[, avg_score := cumsum(score)/(1:.N), by = team]

#    team score avg_score
# 1:    A    10        10
# 2:    A     4         7
# 3:    A    10         8
# 4:    A    16        10
# 5:    A    20        12
# 6:    B     5         5
# 7:    B    11         8
# 8:    B     8         8
# 9:    B    16        10
# 10:    B     5         9
```

Comment: Smooth! But maybe slightly more readable like this: `setDT(dt)[, avg_score := cumsum(score)/(1:.N), by = team]`?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an R base solution

```
df$avg_score <- unlist(tapply(df$score, df$team, function(x) cumsum(x)/seq_along(x)))
> df
   team score avg_score
1     A    10        10
2     A     4         7
3     A    10         8
4     A    16        10
5     A    20        12
6     B     5         5
7     B    11         8
8     B     8         8
9     B    16        10
10    B     5         9
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `cummean` from `dplyr` (also noted that @aosmith commented it - assuming that he is not posting it as solution)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(team) %>%
    mutate(avg_score = cummean(score))
#     team score avg_score
#    <chr> <int>     <dbl>
#1      A    10        10
#2      A     4         7
#3      A    10         8
#4      A    16        10
#5      A    20        12
#6      B     5         5
#7      B    11         8
#8      B     8         8
#9      B    16        10
#10     B     5         9
```